# Cant install vagrant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vagrant

I tried to clean some images from boot, and i think i screwed soemthing =/
I had vagrant installed, and i think that during the process it was removed, and now when i try to install it i get:

```
xx@xxxx:~/dev/devmachine/test$ sudo apt-get install vagrant
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-63-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-63-generic but it is not going to be installed
 vagrant : Depends: bsdtar but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-childprocess (>= 0.3.7) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-erubis (>= 2.7.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-i18n (>= 0.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-log4r (>= 1.1.9) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-net-scp (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-net-ssh (>= 1:2.6.6) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby-net-ssh (< 1:2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: ruby1.9.1 but it is not going to be installed
N: Ignoring file '20auto-upgrades.ucf-dist' in directory '/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Did you try `apt-get -f install`, as suggested?

Comment: And after `$ sudo apt-get -f install` ,  you can run the install command, which is  :  `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vagrant`